# When should I use a function instead of a variable in Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I have written two Sudoku solvers in Z3, once using 81 variables, and once using a function that maps x and y coordinates to the number in square[x][y].
I guess one could also use an Array instead.

What is the difference between having a python array of Z3 variables, having a Z3 array or having a function in Z3? 
When should I use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generally applicable answer to this question. There is usually more than one way to model a problem and it's never clear which one will be the best in practice. As a general rule it makes sense to keep it within one theory as that avoids costly cross-theory reasoning; i.e., stick with bit-vectors or (bounded) integers, but don't try to translate integers to bit-vectors (e.g., the `int2bv` term is essentially treated as uninterpreted by Z3). Also, it's known that there are better solutions for solving problems with arrays, than the one implemented in Z3, so if they are not really necessary it helps to eliminate them.